# NEW_OUTGOING_CALL not being called on Samsung Galaxy S

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Trying to intercept outgoing calls, and have a solution working well on

- nexus 1 stock android 2.2
- HTC desire 2.2
- Moto defy 2.1

But not on the Samsung Galaxy S running 2.1, anyone seen this?

```
 <receiver  android:name="com.mypackge.OutGoingCallDetection" 
    android:exported="true"> 
 <intent-filter>   
  <action
    android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"
    android:priority="0" /> 
</intent-filter> 
</receiver>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

Update: the PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS is also added.

The receiver:

```
public class OutGoingCallDetection extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "OutGoingCallDetection";


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive, Action:" +intent.getAction());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting the manifest in order as suggested by Google Dev: [Manifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Like this:

```
<uses-permission />
...
<receiver>
    <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
    <meta-data />
</receiver>
```

There may be an issue in how some devices parse the Manifest and may not register the receiver correctly.

**EDIT: As of ADT 16 Lint will tell you that your permissions are in the wrong place, so I'm assuming this must be more of an issue then previously thought**

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the user permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

See [this blog post](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1151) as an example of how to setup and use the NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.

Also see [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html) as to what to set your `android:priority` to.

Comment: I have the PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS permission (otherwise it wouldn't work on other devices). I'm using priority 0 after reading the Android blog post, but I'll experiment with priority and post back. Thanks

Comment: ummm weird... I have run NEW_OUTGOING_CALL on lots of Samsung Galaxy S devices without problem, including devices that run Android 2.1 without any problems.

Comment: my guess would be that something is installed on your device that is aborting the broadcast, so lower priority broadcasts are not getting a show in?  so yeah, up the priority and see what you see.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to increase `android:priority`? Let's say up to 10000.

I was intercepting incoming SMS' and increasing of `android:priority` attribute was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I created the broadcast listener programmatically. It works fine. For your reference.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");

receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive, Action:" +intent.getAction());
    }
};
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```