# android : not getting new outgoing call broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, call

i have defined a receiver for NEW_OUTGOING_CALL broadcast. But this is not getting invoked.

In my app i have other broadcastreceivers 
(phone state, package change) and its all getting invoked.

Please see my android manifest below
I also tried changing the order of definition of receivers (put them before activities etc).

**manifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<!-- permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!-- Features -->
<!-- <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" /> -->
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <!-- Activities -->
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activites.helper.ShowPopUp" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.InnerWindowActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.VaultDetailSmsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.LocationActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.VaultSettingsActivity" >
    </activity>
    <!-- Receivers -->
    <receiver android:name=".listeners.OutgoingCallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".listeners.PackageChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />

            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".listeners.PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".listeners.VaultSmsBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!--
             <intent-filter android:priority="101">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />

                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:priority="101">
                <action android:name="com.android.mms.transaction.MESSAGE_SENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        -->
    </receiver>
    <!-- Services -->
    <service android:name=".services.CallLogContentObserverService" >
    </service>
    <service android:name=".services.SentSmsContentObserverService" >
    </service>
    <service android:name=".services.LocationService" >
    </service>
</application>
```

**OutgoingCallReceiver.java**

```
 package com.idg.idvault.listeners;


 import com.idg.idvault.activities.IDVaultActivity;

 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         final String originalNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

         this.setResultData("0123456789");

         final String newNumber = this.getResultData();

         String msg = "Intercepted outgoing call. Old number " + originalNumber + ", new number " + newNumber;

         Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         Log.i("OutgoingCallInterceptor", "OutgoingCallInterceptor");
         if (originalNumber.equals("**434*")) {
             setResultData(null);

             Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, IDVaultActivity.class);
             intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             context.startActivity(intent1);
         }


     }

 }
```

Comment: I got answer soon after posting the question. I should add permission  <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/> . Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>`  permission for processing outgoing calls in manifest.xml

Comment: Appears there are numerous cases where Samsung phones are not broadcasting this, but not all Samsung phones, so your milage may vary.

Comment: This is not working for me on the emulator. Anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check this. There could be an issue with the order in manifest file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6707482/1403112