# Can't receive NEW_OUTGOING_CALL

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I tried to start a activity by dialing a certain number. But I can't receive `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` broadcast on the HTC g17. Here is my code.

```
    <receiver android:name="com.example.security.receiver.CallPhoneReceiver">
        <intent-filter >
            <action 
                android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"
                android:priority="10000"/>
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and I have added the permission like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

and my receiver function is

```
package com.example.security.receiver;

import com.example.security.ui.LostProtectedActivity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class CallPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("annoy",this.getResultData());
    String outPhoneNumber = this.getResultData();
    if(outPhoneNumber.equals("201314")){
        Intent i = new Intent(context,LostProtectedActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   
        context.startActivity(intent);
        setResultData(null);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: It should be working, but try to change `android:priority` to 0 maybe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6696652/1321873

Comment: I've seen that question,but it didn't solve my problem. I've put the permission before the receiver code.:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out yet.There is a mistake in the "CallPhoneReciever".It should be

```
context.startActivity(i);
```

not

```
context.startActivity(intent);
```

And I find it's better to set the priority to 2147483647 (the max value of int), it is prior than 1000. But granted that priority is 2147483647, there are some applications made by some big company, they will register the `BroadcastReceiver` dynamically when the telephone is starting up, and these application will receive the broadcast early than applications that are registered statically.